# Sugarizer won't start

Tags: 18.04

So last weekend I played with Sugarizer for a bit with my lo, this weekend I try and the application just does not start. Nothing happens if I launch from the gui, nothing happens from the cl, but running as sudo gives an error message:

```
error mkdir cannot create directory '/run/user/0'
```

My question: what can I do to figure out more about what is happening?

I'm running 18.04 freshly installed and fully updated, on an Asus Zenbook.

---------- update ----------
So still no change, I even tried freshly reinstalling the OS again. I have no idea why the program worked a week ago as nothing seems to help. I can only assume some update to the OS broke something...

But whatever, I downloaded an appimage file from Sugarizer's website and that works just fine.

Comment: I think it's the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1751634

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: That bug does look right, for the sudo issue. Does that explain why it won't launch normaly though?

Comment: I installed the application through the store.